# How do I automatically create Test Cases in VSTS from existing Unit Tests?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, azure-devops

I've got over 1000 Unit Tests that I want to be linked to Test Cases in VSTS (for traceability). However, the only built-in way of doing this that I can see is to manually create a Test Case in VSTS for each Unit Test method, then manually assign the Unit Test method to the Test Case using Visual Studio.

Manually creating over 1000 Test Cases in VSTS doesn't seem like a good idea, so I'm wondering if there are any existing alternatives that could automate the process (before I go down the route of knocking up a script myself)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using tcm.exe you can import all unit tests in dll to VSTS.

Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff942471(v=vs.100).aspx link for more information and let us know.

Comment: That looks like it'll do the job, thanks.